# Qt Ministro error

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt-necessitas, ministro

im using necessitas 3.X
base on qt 4.8.0 32 bit
MINISTRO 2 VERSION 9.6
My Program doesn't have any problem nor on tablets (brand: Samsung Company) neither on Android (version 2_4.3 )
But I have problems with asus fonepad while downloading MINIStRO.actually it illustrates this "error messege" :
"can not satisfy your application's dependencies"
Although I'm using ministro configuratin,I can not solve this problem!
furtheremore, I also have enought free space in my tablet.

Comment: Can you show your resources xml? Also, I would encourage to upgrade to Qt 5. Things will look lotta better.

Comment: Can not use gps and qt mobility in qt 5.2 . asus fonepad proccessor INTEL ATOM X86

Comment: Mobility mostly has better alternative in Qt 5 AFAIK, either way, please paste the android lib xml. Mobility is not well supported in the Necessaitas project, including Ministro. See the following open report for details: http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/tickets/104/ What happens if you make a test without mobility (and/or QtMultiMedia)?

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<resources>
    <array name="bundled_libs"/>
    <array name="qt_libs">
        <item>QtCore</item>
        <item>QtGui</item>
        <item>QtNetwork</item>
        <item>QtSql</item>
        <item>QtLocation</item>
        <item>QtSystemInfo</item>
        <item>QtXml</item>
    </array>
</resources>

Comment: I would try to remove QtLocation and QtSystemInfo (and the relevant code for sure) to see if the error goes away.

Comment: can not remove QtLocation and QtSystemInfo beacuse use in my app

Comment: That is why I wrote for _testing_.

Comment: So, please provide that information, and make sure you go not get the old xml, so I would try to remove it before the experiment to get it regenerated.

Comment: Did you make sure it is not a network problem? Also, which device is this?

Comment: step1 : remove QtLocation and QtSystemInfo step2:Deploy For Android With Necesitas 3.X Step3: When Download Lib Error Message : "can not satisfy your application's dependencies

Comment: How To Deploy my app For android(QT 5.2) with gps ?

Comment: It really is hard to tell without more concrete information...

Comment: asus fonepad proccessor INTEL ATOM X86. necessitas can to support the inte Atom processor?

Comment: network : test;Galaxy p3100 :test;samsung note3 :test;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the KDE wiki page below, it seems that the Necessitas project has not finished the support for x86. It is possible it will not be finished any soon either since BogDan (the maintainer behind) and other contributors are working on Qt 5 these days.

[Necessitas/TODO](http://community.kde.org/Necessitas/TODO)

In general, you should port away from QtMobility towards Qt 5.2 and on. There is a QtLocation add-on module in its repository. The porting should be more or less smooth.

Comment: My app Run In x86 system when use qt 5.2 , but can not use gps? qt 5.2 can not support gps

Comment: I am afraid, you are wrong: Qt 5.2 does support GPS with QtLocation. Even if it was not, you could not use Ministro as per answer and KDE wiki.

Comment: Do you can send me example code for use gps in qt 5.2 in android?

Comment: See the examples in the module... But this has nothing to do with your original question. Please stick to one question per thread.

Comment: @user2110524: why do you stop replying to the people who are trying to help with this? :)

Comment: My problem Is Fix . Im Using Qt 5.2 . necessitas can not support x86 system